# Send Delivery Reports directly to a folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I would like to ask you if there is any way in Outlook 2010 to send delivery reports in a folder called delivery(for example) directly and not showing them in the inbox folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the `File` tab of the ribbon.

Select `Options`, then `Mail`

You should find an option

```
After updating tracking information, move receipt to:
```

Tick the box and enter your destination folder (e.g. Delivery) in the right-hand side.